# Can't remove the gap between background image and header

Tags: html, css

Trying to remove the gap that exists between the top of the page and my background image.
Tried adjusting with margin in CSS file but nothing is working.

Would greatly appreciate assistance.
Thank you!

[screenshot of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDjqO.png)

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

#header {
-moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
-ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
background: #2e3842;
height: 3em;
left: 0;
line-height: 3em;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="landing">
<div id="page-wrapper">
<header id="header" class="alt">
<h1><a href="index.html">DFKDJDFD</a></h1>
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li class="special">
    <a href="#menu" class="menuToggle"><span>Menu</span></a>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#three">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#cta">Contact</a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li> -->
            </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Where My background Image is added to CSS:

```
   body.landing #page-wrapper {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 0;
    }
```

Comment: did you remove the padding and margin of the body? If not you should

Comment: Please, read some tips how to ask a great question here: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, provide some code you have so far, so that others know where you are stuck and provide meaningful help.

Comment: some css and html code would be useful. if the page is online, you can also send a url

Comment: This should be easy to debug using developer tools - once you get it open you can traverse the HTML and see which element is creating the space, maybe <body> as previously suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did add margin: 0 and padding: 0 to the body and also inside styling for the page wrapper for the image.  It doesn't fix the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: I have a header section where the gap is located where I hide the nav bar which shows the company logo after scrolling down to the following section.  Thinking this might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this on your background image:

```
 position: absolute; top:0;
```

and let me know if this does work or not.

Comment: Jay Try removing background: #2e3842; for  #header  in css in

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS on your image

```
img {
position: absolute;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS will remove the browser default padding and margin.

```
 body{
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 }
```